# is there a built-in b64_decode function within both mySQL and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-injection

I want to do something like

```
select * from `table` where 'fieldname' = built_in_sql_function_to_decode_b64($user_input_that_has_been_b64_encoded)
```

And also, does this technique a reliable technique to be protected against SQL Injection? 
Is it better than the `mysql_real_escape_string` alternative?

Comment: Is this *only* to protect against SQL injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check these out? Also, you will still need to use mysql_real_escape_string to help with SQL injection

[Base64 encode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_to-base64)

[Base64 decode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_from-base64)